# Is the default .gitignore that comes with each new Android Studio project good enough?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, android-studio, gitignore

I'm just wondering if the two .gitignores that are automatically generated with each Android Studio project ignore all the truly unnecessary files? 
When I pushed the project to GitHub, there still seems to be a lot of clutter, but I don't know if it is necessary clutter? 
For example, I'm not sure if all the gradle files are necessary: *gradlew*, *settings.grade*, the *gradle/wrapper* directory, etc.
Here are the default .gitignore files:

The one in the **Project** folder:

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
.idea/
app/app.iml
*.iml
```

And the one in the **app** folder:

```
/build
```

And here's my GitHub repository for a visual of what else got pushed:

https://github.com/quinteroheg2/AndroidWorkspace

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I doubt that you need to ignore IDE-specific files on *repository* basis, not just in `.git/info/exclude`. Most of the aforementioned files are Idea-specific files which indeed shouldn't be committed into the repo. But your co-workers could use other IDEs so technically you should ignore other IDE-specific files as well. Or just make an informal agreement that people in your project(s) don't commit IDE-specific settings and set up `.git/info/exclude` themselves.